# Creating multiple shapefiles from one date within same for loop using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, error-000354

I have imported North American wildfire incident data a comma delimited text file containing one line for each fire incident. Each fire incident has a latitude, longitude coordinate pair separated by commas along with a confidence value.

My first task was to create a shapefile, and make the data usable to import into the attribute table of the shapefile I created called *Incidents*.

My new task is to repeat this process in a new shapefile within my MDB. The shapefile is called *NewFires* by user input. My issue is that when I run the code a second time, I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing
>   IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 29, in 
>   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 1807, in
>   CreateFeatureclass
>       raise e arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters Failed to execute (CreateFeatureclass).

My second shapefile starts with 'if 'Confidence' in fire:'

```
import arcpy

work = raw_input("Enter the full path of WildlandFires.mdb: ") # C:\Scripts\Lab 7 Data\WildlandFires.mdb
arcpy.env.workspace = work # Set the workspace to the geodatabase
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

iFile = raw_input("Enter the full path of wildfire text file: ")# input text file C:\Scripts\Lab 7 Data\NorthAmericaWildfires_2007275.txt  
output = raw_input("Enter the name of the output feature class: ")

f = open(iFile, 'r')# input text file C:\Scripts\Lab 7 Data\NorthAmericaWildfires_2007275.txt in "read" mode

lstFires = f.readlines() # Read the lines of fire data from the input file
f.close() # close the file 

fields = ["SHAPE@", "CONFIDENCE"] # represents the field names for each row in the feature class

# Process: Create Feature Class
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(work, "Incidents.shp", "POINT", "C:\\Scripts\\Lab 7 Data\\WildlandFires.mdb\\FireIncidents")

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("Incidents.shp", fields) # add the new points that you will create to the "FireIncidents" feature class

cntr = 0 # counter variable

for fire in lstFires:
        if 'Latitude' in fire: # Skip the header
            continue
        pnt = arcpy.Point() # Create a new Point object
        lstValues = fire.split(',') # create a list of values "lstValues" based on the type of delimiter
        str_int = lstValues [-3:]       
        str_int = list(map(float, str_int)) #turns string to integers
        latitude = str_int[0] # Latitude
        longitude = str_int[1] # Longitude
        confid = str_int[2] # Confidence Value 

        pnt.X = longitude # Assign the X and Y properties of the Point object
        pnt.Y = latitude 

       if 'Confidence' in fire:  # Skip the header
            continue
        output = arcpy.Point() # Create a new Point Object
        arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(work, "NewFires", "POINT", "'C:\\Scripts\\Lab 7 Data\\Incidents.shp'")
        arcpy.AddField_management(NewFires_shp, "CONFIVALUE", "FLOAT")
        field = ["SHAPE@", "CONFIDENCE"] # represents the field names for each row in the feature class       
        row = [pnt, confid] # Create a new row for the feature class        
        cursor.insertRow(row) # Insert the new row to the feature class

        cntr = cntr + 1 # update the counter
        print "Record # " + str(cntr) + " written to feature class"  

del cursor # release the cursor lock on the feature class
```

Comment: An mdb is a geodatabase into which you can import a shapefile as a feature class. You can't create a shapefile within a geodatabase - they are completely different file formats. Lose the '.shp' to create a feature class rather than shapefile.

Comment: @phloem that worked

Comment: @phloem You should put that as an answer

Comment: Sure, I just wasn't sure if that was the only problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An MDB is a (Personal) Geodatabase into which you can import a Shapefile, as a feature class within a Geodatabase. A Shapefile is a type of feature class that can exist outside of a Geodatabase, but you can't create a Shapefile within a Geodatabase - they are completely different file formats.

Lose the '.shp' to create a Geodatabase feature class, rather than a Shapefile.